# Visual Studio 2017 - How to get the current running edition from ENVDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm working on a VSIX package port to Visual Studio 2017 and I need to get the running edition from the VSPackage (Enterprise, Community etc..).

Looking at the [ENVDTE interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.version?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017) it's pretty straightforward to get the version number, but not the edition. Up to VS 2013 it was possible at least to retrieve the installed edition [from the registry](https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx) but it seems it's not the case anymore as VS2017 uses a [its own private registry](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/category/vs-15/).

Does anyone have an idea on how to get the current running Visual Studio 2017 edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the readonly property `_DTE.Edition?`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.edition?view=visualstudiosdk-2017